# Adding images to HTML table cell via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just trying to do this but I keep getting only `countries[i].Code` instead of the image, can anyone help me out with this ?

```
function flist(){
  var list = document.querySelector("#flist");  
  var myRows = "";  

  for(var i=0; i < countries.length; i++){           
        myRows += "<tr>" +
                  "<td>" + "<figure>" + "<img src=" + "\"" + "/flags/"+ countries[i].Code  + 
                  ".png" + "\"" +  "alt=" + "\"" + countries[i].Code  + "\"" + "height=" +"\""+ "14"+ "\"" +  " width=" + "\"" +"14" + "\""+ ">" +"</figure>" + "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + countries[i].Code + "</td>" + 
                 "<td>" + countries[i].Name.English + "</td>" + 
                 "<td>" + countries[i].Continent + "</td>" + 
                 "<td>" + countries[i].AreaInKm2.toString()+ "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + countries[i].Population.toString() + "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + countries[i].Capital + "</td>" +
                 "</tr>";
  }

  list.innerHTML += myRows; 
};
```

Example of Countires

var countries = [
  {
    Code: "AF",
    Continent: "Asia",
    AreaInKm2: 652230,
    Population: 35530081,
    Capital: "Kabul",
    Name: {
      "English": "Afghanistan",
      "Arabic": "أفغانستان",
      "Chinese": "阿富汗",
      "Franch": "Afghanistan",
      "Hindi": "अफ़ग़ानिस्तान",
      "Korean": "아프가니스탄",
      "Japanese": "アフガニスタン",
      "Russian": "Афганистан"
    }

Im trying to make a table in the HTML of each county and in the begging to have a flag

```
<h4 id="subtitle">List of Countries and Dependencies</h4>
<table id="outputTable">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Flag</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th id="countyrName">Country/Dep. Name</th>             
        <th>Continent</th>
        <th>Area (Km<sup>2</sup>)</th>
        <th>Population</th>
        <th>Capital</th>
      </tr>    
  </thead>

  <tbody id="flist"></tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Hey, so this question is a little incomplete it's missing a lot of code and explanation, what are you trying to make? what path are you using for the images? etc. also you have some nesting issues right here --> "alt"="\""you need to use "alt" = "\'" notice the (') if you use a two " when nesting in JavaScript it'll interpret your string improperly could be part of your issue but idk you need to elaborate

Comment: Please reformat your code using template literals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals This will make your code much more easy to read.

Comment: Here's a hot tip because your knew use the @ symbol when responding to us so we can get a notification of your comment

Comment: Please check the path of the image source. Make sure the src point to the image.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including some test data for `countries`

Comment: @Andrew Hansen i have edited with more info

Comment: @Kevin Z. Li Files are : flags(this is where flags are) , js(Code location) both of this files are in the single file

Comment: Also, make sure all your slashes are forward ones, "/" and not backslashes, "\". src will never recognize backslashes.

Comment: can we get an example of code source, also try logging your path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be keeping your HTML as HTML, keep it out of the JavaScript. If you change from a `table` to `ul` you now have to go rewrite your javascript.

Set a hidden template. Make a copy of the template to work with and remove the template all together. Then you can clone the template an replace values as needed without needing to worry about your HTML structure.

```js
var countries = [{
      Code: "AF",
      Continent: "Asia",
      AreaInKm2: 652230,
      Population: 35530081,
      Capital: "Kabul",
      Name: {
        "English": "Afghanistan",
        "Arabic": "أفغانستان",
        "Chinese": "阿富汗",
        "Franch": "Afghanistan",
        "Hindi": "अफ़ग़ानिस्तान",
        "Korean": "아프가니스탄",
        "Japanese": "アフガニスタン",
        "Russian": "Афганистан"
      }}]

    //Make a clone out of tempate 
    var template = document.getElementById("rowTemplate").cloneNode(true);
    template.removeAttribute("id")
    console.log(template);

    //get rid of original we done't  need it any more
    document.getElementById("flist").innerHTML = "";

    function flist() {
      var list = document.querySelector("#flist");
      var myRows = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        //make a working copy of the template
        var workingTemplate = template.cloneNode(true);
        //Do the replace
        workingTemplate.innerHTML = workingTemplate.innerHTML
        .replace(/{{code}}/g, countries[i].Code)
        .replace(/{{name}}/g, countries[i].Name.English)
        .replace(/{{continent}}/g, countries[i].Continent)
        .replace(/{{area}}/g, countries[i].AreaInKm2)
        .replace(/{{population}}/g, countries[i].Population)
        .replace(/{{capital}}/g, countries[i].Capital);     
        
        myRows += workingTemplate.outerHTML;
      }

      //update the table
      list.innerHTML += myRows;
    };
    
    flist();
```

```css
#rowTemplate {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h4 id="subtitle">List of Countries and Dependencies</h4>
<table id="outputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Flag</th>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th id="countyrName">Country/Dep. Name</th>
      <th>Continent</th>
      <th>Area (Km<sup>2</sup>)</th>
      <th>Population</th>
      <th>Capital</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="flist">
    <tr id="rowTemplate">
      <td class="img">
        <figure><img src="/flags/{{code}}" alt="{{code}}" height="14" width="14"></figure>
      </td>
      <td>{{code}}</td>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
      <td>{{continent}}</td>
      <td>{{area}}</td>
      <td>{{population}}</td>
      <td>{{capital}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use singles quotes for dealing with building HTML in javascript, you don't have to escape the double quotes around params and is less prone to making mistakes.

```
myRows += '<tr>' +
'<td><figure><img src="/flags/' + countries[i].Code + '.png" alt="' + countries[i].Code + '" height="14" width="14" /></figure></td>' +
'<td>' + countries[i].Code + '</td>' + 
'<td>' + countries[i].Name.English + '</td>' + 
'<td>' + countries[i].Continent + '</td>' + 
'<td>' + countries[i].AreaInKm2.toString()+ '</td>' +
'<td>' + countries[i].Population.toString() + '</td>' +
'<td>' + countries[i].Capital + '</td>' +
'</tr>';
```

Comment: I have tried it before but it doesnt work with single once

Comment: @AleksandrStepanenko at least part of your issue is you're not escaping your quotes try console.log() of what your inputing and you'll see it doesn't call the source properly

Comment: @Andrew Hansen  when i input this  <figure><img src="flags/af.png" alt="af" height="14" width="14" ></figure>  in the HTMl it shows the image

Comment: @AleksandrStepanenko console.log your code to see if it is the same as that like this console.log(<img src=" + "\"" + "/flags/"+ countries[i].Code  + 
                  ".png" + "\"" +  "alt=" + "\"" + countries[i].Code  + "\"" + "height=" +"\""+ "14"+ "\"" +  " width=" + "\"" +"14" + "\""+ ">") I think you'll find that because of the improper nesting it won't equal it won't be the same

Comment: @ Andrew Hansen when i do it , it doesnt show even the table.

Comment: @AleksandrStepanenko it shouldn't it should just send the data to the console -the  console is the best tool in a developers aresnol to view the console go to the tab in the browser your using and hit cntrl + shift + I to view then click on console on the top bar and it'll feed you things that you print to the console and in the console you can check the exact syntax of string you're creating and compare it to the element you made that worked and use it to fix your string editor

Comment: @Andrew Hansen its undefined

Comment: @AleksandrStepanenko Then you need to rexamine your code, it's not formatting the string properly use different types of quoations when nesting data in JS